# Flask dev server limits

Tags: python, flask, request

I implemented a REST API using flask and I am wondering what is the limit of the dev. server?

I mean why investing time and money to deploy the api on a prod server while the dev. server can support the traffic.

To avoid marking the question as duplicate, I am not asking for security risks, I want to know what are the limits of the flask dev. server in term of request/seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides performance you want an outfacing service (like a webserver) to be as secure as possible. The flask development server is not developed with high security as a goal, so there are probably sercurity relevant bugs.